# Axapta v3.0 with SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, compatibility, axapta, sql-server-2005-express

I managed to find an old Axapta version to practice some programming and learn Axapta a little. The problem is I can't get it started. I had installed SP1-2-3 and started it, it is supposed to create the database. Well it creates some tables then I get a syntax error from SQL Server. I am told even SP1 was enough for SQL 2005. The error is 'Incorrect syntax near INDEX'. I don't know what to do at the moment. I am waiting for a friend to dl SQL 2000 from MSDNAA. If there are any Axapta experts here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narsil, there is another option to make Axapta sp1 work with SQL Server 2005. Just open properties of your database in Management studio, go to 'options' tab and set compatibility mode to SQL Server 2000 - (80). Afterwards run Axapta synchronization again. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

For Axapta v3.0 to work with SQL Server 2005, you will need to apply the Kernel Rollups (KR), which you can't on SP1. I believe SP2 is a minimum for KR2 which will you get you working on SQL Server 2005.

If you are only going to have a small database to learn Axapta, instead of SQL Server 2005 you can use MSDE with SP4. You can get it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=8e2dfc8d-c20e-4446-99a9-b7f0213f8bc5).

I have not tried Axapta v3 with KR2 or KR3 running on SQL Server 2005 Express, so I don't know if this even works. Looking at the KR2/3 documentation it does not look like it is supported.